# sh - remove text outside two strings

Tags: sed, sh, aix

I need help to filter a part of text from my original logs:

```
    <variable>  
  <status type="String"><![CDATA[-1]]></status>
  <errorCode type="String"><![CDATA[[bpm]]]></errorCode>
  <mensagens type="MensagemSistema[]">
    <item>
      <msg_err type="String"><![CDATA[ERROR1-This is error: - THIS TEXT IS VARIABLE.]]</msg_err>
      <msg_err_stack type="String"><![CDATA[stack_trace]]></msg_err_stack>
    </item>
  </mensagens>
</variable>
```

The part that I want is:

```
<msg_err type="String"><![CDATA[ERROR1-This is error: - THIS TEXT IS VARIABLE.]]>
```

... and this text is variable.

I tried to perform this with sed, but I wouldn't find a example to remove text outside two strings. Just another thing this is unix

thanks in advance
Tiago

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I just need the : ERROR1-This is error 1., but I think my problem is essentially remove the outter text of the line in example

Comment: is the log a well-formed xml?

Comment: Don't use `sed`; it's not an XML parser.

Comment: well this is aix, and I think there is nothing available in this system to make it, and this is a customer environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo '<msg_err type="String"><![CDATA[ERROR1-This is error 1.]]></msg_err>' | sed 's/.*\[\([^][]*\).*/\1/g'
ERROR1-This is error 1.
```

Comment: sorry, I forgotten to refer something, I'm going edit the original message

Comment: I tried others things, but at the end I used your approach with grep. This version of AIX is very limited

Comment: You don't need the grep.  Add -n as an argument and a p at the end of the pattern thus: sed -n 's/.*\[\([^][]*\).*/\1/pg'  --- Also, do you want the g at the end?  That means replace multiple times but I think you will hit only once because of the .* at the end.  Sooo... make it: sed -n 's/.*\[\([^][]*\).*/\1/p'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for an XML parser. The Perl module [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) is capable of retrieving the data you want:

```
perl -MXML::Simple -e '$xml = XMLin(\*STDIN); print $xml->{'mensagens'}->{'item'}->{'msg_err'}->{'content'};' < error.xml
```

Output:

```
ERROR1-This is error: - THIS TEXT IS VARIABLE.
```

Note that I added a `>` to close the CDATA in the `msg_err` tag, as I assumed this to be a typo.

Comment: I tried this but, don't work ... This is a result of a stack trace / run time error, saved in table of the system.

Comment: Without more details it's impossible to say why. Assuming the parsing was successful, you might want to try using `Data::Dumper` to print the `$xml` variable and work out exactly what part you want to extract. If you have some more details, you should edit your question.